# Update script failed to fetch on start-up

Tags: debian, apt, startup

I'm working on Debian 9.7.0 without desktop environment.
I've made a script to update my packages and I added in /etc/crontab to run on start-up. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

When I'm running it manually it works just fine, but on start-up apt-get won't fetch debian url.
Here are the logs:

```
Err:1 http:///ftp.be.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.be.debian.org'
Err:2 http://ftp.be.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.be.debian.org'
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I'm not mistaken apt-get cannot access the debian servers?

Edit: I also tried to change the servers in /etc/apt/sources.list but I still got the same errors.

Does someone knows how comes and how to deal with it?

I couldn't find any answer, so hopefully this is not a repost. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this script is running before your network is up.

I would advise using a `systemd` service which will run at boot, this way to can require it runs once your network is up.

For example:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/update.service
[Unit]
Description=Apt Update & Upgrade
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
KillMode=process
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/update-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable update.service
```

Alternatively, I would probably just use the `unattended-upgrades` package to do all of this.